# Is there any way to create "fragile" attributes in R?

Tags: r, class, attributes

Is there any way to set an attribute on an object that is removed when it is processed by another function?  For example, I might write:

```
weightedMeanZr <- function(r,n) {
   require(psych)
   Zr <- fisherz(r) 
   ZrBar <- sum(Zr*(n-3))/(sum(n-3))
   attr(ZrBar,"names") <- "ZrBar"
   return(ZrBar)
}
```

To calculated the weighted fisher transformed Z average for a set of correlations.  However, if I convert it back into an r, e.g.

```
require(psych)
bdata <- structure(list(Sample = 1:6, n = c(4L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 11L, 14L), 
    r = c(0.93, 0.57, 0.46, -0.09, 0.12, 0.32)), .Names = c("Sample", 
"n", "r"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

fisherz2r(with(bdata,weightedMeanZr(r,n)))
```

The output value from `fisherz2r` has retained the names attribute from the results of weightedMeanZr.  Is there any way to make that attribute fragile such that being processed by functions like `fisherz2r` removes the names attribute?

**Edit**
Something like what this accomplishes:

```
weightedMeanZr <- function(r,n) {
   require(psych)
   Zr <- fisherz(r) 
   ZrBar <- sum(Zr*(n-3))/(sum(n-3))
   class(ZrBar) <- "ZrBar"
   return(ZrBar)
}
"+.ZrBar" <- function(e1,e2) {
    return(unclass(e1)+unclass(e2))
}
"-.ZrBar" <- function(e1,e2) {
    return(unclass(e1)-unclass(e2))
}
"*.ZrBar" <- function(e1,e2) {
    return(unclass(e1)*unclass(e2))
}
"/.ZrBar" <- function(e1,e2) {
    return(unclass(e1)/unclass(e2))
}
weightedMeanZr(bdata$r,bdata$n)
weightedMeanZr(bdata$r,bdata$n)+1
weightedMeanZr(bdata$r,bdata$n)-1
weightedMeanZr(bdata$r,bdata$n)*2
weightedMeanZr(bdata$r,bdata$n)/2
fisherz2r(weightedMeanZr(bdata$r,bdata$n))
```

... but this only works because fisherz2r calls those particular methods... is there a more general approach?

Comment: What is your use-case? If the attribute were always removed when the object was passed to _any_ function, how would you know it's there in the first place? `print` would drop it, `str` would drop it, etc.

Comment: Good point Joshua.  What I am hoping to do is have the scale of the result travel with the result (for original results and .print).  However, once that result has been transformed in some way, I want the scale to be removed from the object/result so that it doesn't persistently refer to itself by what now might be the wrong scale.

Comment: How do you expect your object to know whether some-unknown-function alters the object in such a way that the object's scale is now incorrect?  I guess there could be a way to create a callback that checks the attribute every time an object is copied, but I'd have to think about that...

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: I was trying to solve a more simple problem, that is just to know if any unknown function altered the object.  When that happened, then I'd get rid of the scale indicator.  But, yes, I couldn't think of any way to create a call back that checks the attribute which is why I posed the question.

Comment: You should be able to get most of the behaviour you want by defining methods for `[<-`, `Maths` and `Ops`.  See https://github.com/hadley/bigvis/blob/master/R/ranged.r for an example

Comment: @hadley: Thanks, that is the best solution by far.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `unname` to remove names

```
 fisherz2r(with(bdata,unname(weightedMeanZr(r,n))))
 # or
 unname(fisherz2(with(bdata,weightedMeanZr(r,n))))
```

or `as.vector`, which in this case will strip the names

Comment: But... no implicit promise to have that sort of thing happen in the future when the results of weightMeanZr are passed to some other function?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a way to automatically do what I am trying to do (at least as of R 2.15.2 as far as I can tell).  There is a callback system in R (thanks go to @JoshuaUlrich for bringing that keyword to mind), but trying to implement the desired behavior may be computationally expensive.

However, here is a (working) example:

```
require(psych)
bdata <- structure(list(Sample = 1:6, n = c(4L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 11L, 14L), 
                        r = c(0.93, 0.57, 0.46, -0.09, 0.12, 0.32)), .Names = c("Sample", 
                                                                                "n", "r"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

weightedMeanZr <- function(r,n) {
  require(psych)
  Zr <- fisherz(r) 
  ZrBar <- sum(Zr*(n-3))/(sum(n-3))
  attr(ZrBar,"original.value") <- ZrBar
  class(ZrBar) <- "ZrBar"
  attr(ZrBar,"names") <- "ZrBar"
  return(ZrBar)
}

h <- taskCallbackManager() #create the callback system

# add a callback
h$add(function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
  cat("In handler",george,"\n")
  ZrBars <- names(which(lapply(sapply(ls(name=.GlobalEnv,all=TRUE),get),class) == "ZrBar"))
  for (i in ZrBars) {
    thisone <- get(i)
    if(!attr(thisone,"original.value") == thisone) {
      attr(thisone,"names") <- NULL
      attr(thisone,"class") <- NULL
      attr(thisone,"original.value") <- NULL
      assign(i,thisone,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}, name = "simpleHandler")

#create some objects of the class
thisone <- weightedMeanZr(runif(10),4:13)
thistoo <- weightedMeanZr(runif(10),4:13)

thisone + 1 #class kept, a print method could be added to resolve this issue
#if we store the result, it goes away as desired
(um <- thisone + 1) #class gone\

#clean out workspace so the callback system doesn't linger
removeTaskCallback("R-taskCallbackManager")
```